# Dirac delta on differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Lets have the next differential equation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x)+\sum_{n}g(t,x)\delta (t-t_n)$$

I have to prove that when $t\in (t_i,t_{i+1})$ for some $i$ then:
 $$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x)$$

For this,  I have to use the next property:
$$\int_{a}^b \! f(x)\delta (x-x_0)dx=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             f(x_0) &   si  & t_1 < x_0 < t_2 \\
             \\0  &  si & x_0 < t_1 \text{ ó } x_0> t_2 \\
            \end{array}\right.$$

Note: I have tried to make the next reassoning:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x)+\sum_{n}g(t,x)\delta (t-t_n) \Rightarrow x(t)= \int_{0}^t a(s,x)ds + \int_{0}^t \sum_{n}b(s,x^-)\delta (s-t_n)ds$$

So, I have to prove that $$\int_{0}^t \sum_{n}b(s,x^-)\delta (s-t_n)ds=0$$ which is not trivial for me :(

Comment: So what have you tried? Right now you've simply set up a problem without showing that you've put any effort or thought into it.

Comment: I have explained a little bit more - @NoseKnowsAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for any $\epsilon>0$, any fixed $i$, and any smooth test function $\phi$

$$\begin{align}
\int_{t_i+\epsilon}^{t_{i+1}-\epsilon}\phi(t)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}dt&=\int_{t_i+\epsilon}^{t_{i+1}-\epsilon}\phi(t)F(x(t),t)dt+\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{t_i+\epsilon}^{t_{i+1}-\epsilon}\phi(t)g(t,x)\delta(t-t_k)dt\\\\
&=\int_{t_i+\epsilon}^{t_{i+1}-\epsilon}\phi(t)F(x(t),t)dt
\end{align}$$

since the Dirac Delta "functions" were not "active" in the interval of integration.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{t_i+\epsilon}^{t_{i+1}-\epsilon}\phi(t)\left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}-F(x(t),t)\right)dt&=0 \tag 1
\end{align}$$

for all test functions $\phi$.  Noting that $(1)$ holds for $\phi(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}-F(x(t),t)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{t_i+\epsilon}^{t_{i+1}-\epsilon}\left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}-F(x(t),t)\right)^2dt&=0 \tag 2
\end{align}$$

The only way for $(2)$ to be zero is if the integrand is zero almost everywhere.  Inasmuch as we assumed that $\phi=x'-F$ is a "smooth" function, then we have $\frac{dx}{dt}=F$ as was to be shown.

Comment: @Edin_91, Dr. MV, the exchange of comments is a good way of making all the details clear. Unfortunately the exchange became rather long, and a system flag was raised. If you both think that  it's all clear now, would you mind deleting the comments. No harm was done - the system flag summoned me here. Time to remove the scaffolding around this piece of art.